# Habitable Planet with Multiple Moons

Tags: moons

I am working on a book with the presence of multiple moons acting as a quasi-astrology based religion whereby the irregular phases of the moons and their relationships between one another allow for 'predictions' to be made about the future.
I have thus far worked with a system of twelve moons (don't all have to appear in the nightsky at once, better the more irregular actually). I'd take fewer, if needed for simplicity, but I do want more than a couple to allow for more complex 'readings' of the night. The really important detail is I need a thirteenth/ or additional rogue moon to appear once every ~1,000 years for magic/plot reasons. The moon does not need to remain in the sky for more than a day.

My concern for now revolves around the plausibility of such a planet. I do not want readers to be thrown out of the book for physics which does not make sense. Apart from regular eclipses and the impact that the different moons would have on tides, is there anything else that I should be adding to my worldbuilding that would legitimise the existence of the planet?

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: About this rogue moon... Does it need to stick around for a while, or is it simply visible for a day or two before departing again?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please read our [help] to understand the kind of questions we do answer and which we don't. Give us the specific of your worldbuilding problem, "I am looking for information" is too vague for us.

Comment: Well, not once a millennium, but we have [Halley's Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley's_Comet) which comes every 72 years or so. And, in general, astrology works fine with our [seven classical planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley's_Comet), and only one of them in a satellite of Earth.

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering @BMF, I would not need need it to hang around more than a day or two. I just need it to have happened at least once in history before.

Comment: I see that this question has been closed. I will spend some time trying to learn a bit more about the stack exchange requirements and then maybe try again via the Sand Box first. I think unfortunately I just don't understand enough about astrophysics to start with to be able to ask more specific questions. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ElsbethAnne My first question is whether or not you need a science-as-we-understand-it-today-perfect planet? Mars has multiple moons, and their size wouldn't cause chaotic tides. We're standing on a habitable planet. So a lot of this (for SE's and our sakes) boils down to, what is the real problem that you're trying to overcome? In a real sense, you might be trying to reinvent the wheel. And that assumes that you need a full-science answer at all. SciFi has been imagining multiple big moons for a long time now.

Comment: This kind of sounds like a "critique my idea question", which is valid here. Elsbeth, the only things I would really recommend is that you edit your marquee question: keep it simple like "Planet with multiple moons". Then, try to display your organisational skills in the body of the question: edit out the personal stuff; edit out the negativity / reasons why it can't work. This is your world! It EXISTS. We just have to deal with its existence! Your second paragraph is pretty good. Really all you need to do is focus on what your world CONSISTS OF; & then tell us what your ACTUAL PROBLEM (cont)

Comment: (cont) actually is! To be honest, I don't see a problem in your underlying question at all. I'm tempted to vote to reopen this now because I think it's perfectly answerable. But if you tweak it a bit, it should be reopened pretty quickly! You might consider the "critique my idea" direction --- that's really for people whose ideas are pretty well developed and they're looking for a higher lever of assistance or a deeper dive into the worldbuilding. I think that's where you are, though I could be wrong!

Comment: @elemtilas Thank you both so much for the feedback, it has been really helpful. I have edited the post and have focused on one issue. Hopefully this is acceptable.

Comment: @JBH I think perhaps I have been focusing too much on the science of it all and not accepting that readers will suspend disbelief in a fantasy world provided that there is some logic behind it. I have been trying to understand the exact science and equations behind it all which was incredibly overwhelming. Thanks for you input.

Comment: @ElsbethAnne No problem. It is very complex. I forget who said it, but an author back in the 1980s once made an observation: as an author, you shouldn't focus on a detail unless you plan on using that detail in the plot. That author wasn't entirely correct: you want enough detail to give the reader a fulfilling experience, but he/she was correct from the perspective that you can chase awfully deep down the rabbit hole of details for no useful purpose. The only people who would appreciate your effort are PhDs in the field. Nobody else will know the difference.

Comment: Looks good Elsbeth! And good luck with your project!

Comment: "Is there anything else that I should be adding to my worldbuilding that would legitimize the existence of the planet?" is far too open ended and subjective a question for this site. The edits definitely improve the question but the core ask is still not the best fit. Is there some specific issue you would like help resolving, or some specific feature you're unsure makes sense? An [edit] to clarify and narrow the scope enables answers that are more focuses and likely to be more helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds really nifty. The planets in our solar system are arranged in a progressive distance from the sun - the outer ones' orbits are farther apart. The sun's gravitational pull on them is weaker because of the farther distance, so if they were the same distance apart their planet-to-planet grav. pull would have a greater tendency disrupt their orbits.

A couple of guys noticed that the orbits' radius, if plotted on a log scale, formed a nearly straight line. One of them was named Bode and it's called Bode's Law. The other guy's name is all but forgotten, for no particular reason.

Twelve moons, if they are not spaced out like that, will exhibit chaotic orbits. Jupiter has a bunch of moons, and a couple of them have orbits right close together. One of our spacecraft (not one that I worked on) discovered that when these two moons pass each other, they exchange orbits.

Another sweet thing: there's a lot of asteroids between Mars and Jupiter. Somebody had the idea that maybe a planet was there (the Mars-Jupe log distance is about 2x the rest, ie. there's an "empty orbit" there) and it got smashed for some reason. You need to read Terry Pratchett's /The Fifth Elephant/ sometime. The world is supported by 4 elephants walking around in a circle, but there were originally 5, one had a rough landing and his bones got shattered, which are the jewels to be found here and there in the earth.

Anyway, if an asteroid there were to have an orbital period of say 2X Jupiter's, it will pass closest to Jupe every other obit, right in the same place every time. The small tug it would get from Jupe would keep perturbing its orbit, so that eventually it would go zingin' off somewhere else. And what'dya know, the asteroid belt's chart has a gap at exactly that place, also 3X and 4X etc.

Now as to your astrology, I'm not into that but I can appreciate that people are. Your planet should have ancient literature that mentions it, as does ours. For instance, Genesis 1:14 (KJ): "And God said, Let there be lights in the firmament of the heaven to divide the day from the night; and let them be FOR SIGNS, and for seasons, and for days, and years." Also there's Revelation 15:1 - "And I saw another sign in heaven, great and marvellous..." I'd think you might have some astrologers, charlatans who claim to read the moons and give predictions, but then one real prophet who reads 'em correctly. Best of luck with it!